# Check in enzym-react how many ul I have in component

Tags: reactjs, chai, enzyme

I would glad to make unit tests to component in simple to-do list.

This is the component:

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Task from '../Task';

export default class TaskList extends Component {

    render() {
        let tasks = this.props.items.map((item,index)=> <Task key={index} item={item} />)

        return (
            <ul>{tasks}</ul>
        )
    }
```

And this is the test:

```
   import TaskList from './';
import Task from '../Task';

describe('<TaskList}/>', () => {
    let wrapper;
    beforeEach(()=>{
        wrapper = shallow(<TaskList items={["item 1", "item 2"]} />);
    })


    it('should have  2 list items', () => {
        expect(wrapper.find('ul')).to.have.length(1);
    })

});
```

No matter what I enter as elemnts of "items" (these are the props of the component) - the amount of 'ul' is allegdly just one.

What is the problem with this test?
How may I check how many 'ul' are in the component?

Answer (score 0):

In order to check how many 'ul' in component we should use chai function:
.childern(), like this:

```
it('should have  2 list items', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('ul').children()).to.have.length(2);
})
```